# When does the touch keyboard popup?

Tags: user-interface, windows-8, keyboard, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a non-touch device (regular PC...) with a keyboard. I've written a Windows 8 App, which includes TextBox.

I want to launch the Touch Keyboard, when the user uses a device without a keyboard (=Tablet/Phone). How can I test it?

I.e. when I use the Visual Studio simulator for Windows 8 and choose "taps" as the gesture, the virtual touch keyboard still won't popup. Is there any specific moment where Windows is using the keyboard automatically? I'd actually like to test the Touch Keyboard to check the InputScope (i.e. InputScope="Number") and the 'look of the app', when the keyboard pops up.

If needed, my TextBox looks like this:

```
<TextBox InputScope="Number"/>
```

Edit: The keyboard pops up now (I don't know why...). I've started the simulator and used "taps" as gesture and the keyboard didn't pop up. After restarting the simulator ~5 times, it pops up now, but the InputScope is not Number...

Comment: this is not an answer :) but since the simulator is a remote desktop session back into  your own machine, for device specific behaviors like sensors and touch, I wouldn't completely rely on the simulator behavior for the correct experience.  Do you have a touch device you can sideload to for a more definitive answer. If not, and you're in the US, check out [App Builder](http://build.windowsstore.com/development-training-events-and-offers) and schedule some time with your local evangelist who has devices you can try your app on.

Comment: I don't live in America, but I'll try to find a tablet or a laptop with touchscreen and test my app on it.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 comes with a Simulator that you can run your Windows 8 app in. On the right of that, you may notice buttons near the top, one that's a pointer and another that's a finger. If you use the finger, then all input will be touch input, as if there were no keyboard.